# HDRP Visual Effects Graph - One particle system is always rendering on top of another

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles, particle-system

**SITUATION**

This is my first time using the VFX Graph. I am making a tornado effect. I just started the process of adding dust particles around the tornado but I already hit an obstacle right off the bat.

**PROBLEM**

For some reason the dust particles keep rendering on top of the tornado.

**DESCRIPTION**

In the "Initialize" context I have a "Set position (Shape: Arc circle)" so they spawn around my tornado. No matter how big I make its radius, they always appear in front of the tornado itself.

**FRONT VIEW**

[image]

**TOP VIEW**

[image]

I tried fiddling with all of the settings that seemed like they could affect this but nothing helped. I have both graphs within the same VFX file:

**TORNADO GRAPH**

[image]

**DUST PARTICLES GRAPH**

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Outside of VFX graph editor, select your VFX object, and in the inspector rearrange the effects to get the desired ordering